# Selenium Webdriver issue with no Frame found

Tags: iframe, selenium, frame, selenium-webdriver

Can someone please help me figure out how to get Selenium Webdriver to find the frame after selecting Sign in??

https://www.guaranteedrate.com/agent/visitors
tap sign in
sendkeys to Username

@Test

```
public void fail() throws InterruptedException {


        driver.findElement(By.linkText("Sign In")).click();
            driver.switchTo().window("GB_window");
            driver.switchTo().frame(0);                driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys("testgr100@gmail.com");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this and tell me if it works?   I suspect that what you are experiencing is a Firefox-only weirdness and a JavaScriptExecutor will get around it.

```
public void setEmailAddrOnFieldInSubFrame() {
    driver.findElement( By.linkText("Sign In") ).click();
    driver.switchTo().window("GB_window");
    driver.switchTo().frame(0);
    WebElement element = driver.findElement( By.id("username") );
    JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
    executor.executeScript( "arguments[0].value='testgr100@gmail.com';", element );

    //cleanup frame position by switching back to previous window
    driver.switchTo().defaultContent(); // always do this cleanup just in case
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think after clicking on Sign in you are taken to a frame, that is the registration form.

What you are trying is to Switch to a window first (GB_Window).

Try removing Switch to window call and just switch to frame and try your operations

After editing your code, use this

```
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("Sign In")).click();
    driver.switchTo().frame(0);
    driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys("testgr100@gmail.com");
```

}

Comment: No no luck it just stays on the frame with the cursor in the email address..it doesn't sendkeys..I have tried many many solutions so far..

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died.
Build info: version: '2.30.0', revision: 'dc1ef9c', time: '2013-02-19 00:15:57'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.6.0_17'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code. It worked for me. There are two frames before you can find Username Element. First frame is GB_frame and the second one doesn't have a any name given in the html source. So i have used index (`frame(0)`) for the second one.

```
@Test

public void fail() throws InterruptedException {    

        driver.findElement(By.linkText("Sign In")).click();
        //switch to frames inside the webpage
        driver.switchTo().frame("GB_frame"); //1st frame
           driver.switchTo().frame(0); //2nd frame              
              driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys("testgr100@gmail.com");
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much that worked had to put thread.sleeps in it though because it was moving too fast

Comment: @Gabriel Alexander Upvote my answer or accept it as a good answer if it has helped you or given you the exact solution.

Answer (score 0):

Well if the application works on firefox then simply right click. In the context menu you will first find out if the element is under a frame or not by seeing an option This frame. Once you confirm this then inspect the element. Scroll top slowly in the firebug and you will find the iframe tag under which the element is present. In this manner you will get to know the name. If you want to know the count of all the iframes and their names then use
driver.findElements(By.tag("iframe")). This will return the list of webelements which have the tag and then you can iterate one by one and use getAttribute("name"). Note this will return the name only if the iframe actually has a name other wise will return empty.